# Jackson how to parse this structure

Tags: json, jackson

I have something like:

```
{"1" : {OBJECT}, "2" : {OBJECT}, "3" : {OBJECT}, ..., "title" : "RandomTitle"}
```

I can't use a simple map as

```
Map<String, OBJECT>
```

because the last item is a String. Do I need to use something like JsonAnySetter and make a custom model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably use of `@JsonAnySetter` makes sense, unless you want to read as `JsonNode` or `Map<String,Object>`.